# Why is statsmodels.api producing R^2 of 1.000?

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I'm using statsmodel to do simple and multiple linear regression and I'm getting bad R^2 values from the summary.  The coefficients look to be calculated correctly, but I get an R^2 of 1.000 which is impossible for my data.  I graphed it in excel and I should be getting around 0.93, not 1.

I'm using a mask to filter data to send into the model and I'm wondering if that could be the issue, but to me the data looks fine.  I am fairly new to python and statsmodel so maybe I'm missing something here.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

    for i, df in enumerate(fallwy_xy):   # Iterate through list of dataframes
        if len(df.index) > 0:            # Check if frame is empty or not
            mask3 = (df['fnu'] >= low)   # Mask data below 'low' variable
            valid3 = df[mask3]
            if len(valid3) > 0:          #  Check if there is data in range of mask3
                X = valid3[['logfnu', 'logdischarge']]
                y = valid3[['logssc']]
                estm = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
                X = valid3[['logfnu']]
                y = valid3[['logssc']]
                ests = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
```

Comment: I cut the code down to a simple csv with a single data set.  Same problem...

Comment: sklearn produces correct values.  The plot thickens.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found out what was going on.  Statsmodels by default does not incorporate a constant into its OLS regression equation, you have to call it out specifically with

```
X = sm.add_constant(X)
```

The reason the constant is so important is because without it, Statsmodels calculates R-squared differently, uncentered to be exact.  If you do add a constant then the R-squared gets calculated the way most people calculate R-squared which is the centered version.  Excel does not change the way it calculates R-squared when given a constant or not which is why when Statsmodels reported it's R-squared with no constant it as so different from Excel.  The OLS Regression summary from Statsmodels actually points out the calculation method if it uses the uncentered no-constant, calculation by showing R-squared (uncentered): where the R-squared shows up in the summary table.  The below links helped me figure this out.

[add hasconstant indicator for R-squared and df calculations](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/27/)

[Same model coeffs, different R^2 with statsmodels OLS and sci-kit learn linearregression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413430/same-model-coeffs-different-r2-with-statsmodels-ols-and-sci-kit-learn-linearre)

[Warning : Rod Made a Mistake!](http://www.sfu.ca/~maki/Web/mistake.htm)

Comment: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/510040/statsmodels-ols-r2-calculation)
Can you check this question also?